# positioning html element using css style

Tags: css

I kept image and some text as given below:

[CODEPAN](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/wmBvd)

```
  <div class="container">
                <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-4.jpg" height="40"  width="200" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
                <h5>S o m e t e x t h e r e</h5>      

  </div>
```

It shows distance between image and text.

Css style for `h5` is on bottom is css block. How can I adjust it just below the image?

Comment: Your codepAn is empty

Comment: Your CodePen is empty. Also, please include your CSS here in your post so we can better understand your problem.

Comment: Please check codepan again

Comment: @Alien: I put correct pan

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS rule:

```
   h5{
    margin-left:0;
    }
```

Comment: You are using `margin-left:2%;` in your CSS code. That's what causing it at the moment.